# Oracle/PHP "Invalid Identifier" Errors

Tags: php, oracle, view

I'm really not sure what's going on at this point. I'm trying to create a view, and when I run the query below:

```
$view = oci_parse($conn, '
                CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 
                    V_ORD_HISTORY
                AS 
                SELECT
                    ARCUSTO.ID,
                    ORDERS.ID,
                    ORDERS.PONO,
                    ORDERS.ORDERNO,
                    ORDERS.DATE_TAKEN,
                    ORDERS.ARCUSTO_ID,
                    ORD_DETAIL.ORDERS_ID,
                    ORD_DETAIL.ID,
                    ORD_DETAIL.TOTAL_QTY_ORD,
                    ORD_DETAIL.CUMM_SHIPPED,
                    ORD_DETAIL.DISCOUNT,
                    ORD_DETAIL.UNIT_PRICE
                FROM
                    ARCUSTO a,
                    ORDERS  o,
                    ORD_DETAIL d,
                    ARINVT i
                WHERE
                    a.ID = o.ARCUSTO_ID
                AND
                    d.ORDERS_ID = o.ID
            ');
```

I get the error:

```
ORA-00904: "ORD_DETAIL"."UNIT_PRICE": invalid identifier
```

And if I try to delete ***ORD_DETAIL.UNIT_PRICE*** from the end of the select statement, then it tells me that ***ORD_DETAIL.DISCOUNT*** is now the invalid identifier. Whichever column is last in the list becomes the invalid identifier. If I remove the prefix to determine which table, then I get column ambiguously defined errors.

Any ideas??

**EDIT 1**

I've now changed the code to the following:

```
$view = oci_parse($conn, '
                CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 
                    V_ORD_HISTORY
                AS 
                SELECT
                    a.ID as CUSTOMER_ID,
                    o.ID as ORD_ID,
                    o.PONO,
                    o.ORDERNO,
                    o.DATE_TAKEN,
                    o.ARCUSTO_ID,
                    d.ORDERS_ID,
                    d.ID as DETAIL_ID,
                    d.TOTAL_QTY_ORD,
                    d.CUMM_SHIPPED,
                    d.DISCOUNT,
                    d.UNIT_PRICE
                FROM
                    ARCUSTO a,
                    ORDERS  o,
                    ORD_DETAIL d,
                    ARINVT i
                WHERE
                    CUSTOMER_ID = o.ARCUSTO_ID
                AND
                    ORD_ID = d.ORDERS_ID
            ');
```

But now it's saying that ***ORD_ID*** is an invalid identifier. This its the last line of the SQL statment.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper,, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Qualify reference  to the `UNIT_PRICE` with the alias `d` you gave to the `ORD_DETAIL` table, not with the table name itself. If you want to qualify reference to that column with the table name, remove the alias. Same goes for any other column referenced in your query.

Comment: Okay, I think I've almost got it.. Look at edit #1 above.

Comment: are you refering `ORD_ID ` from the alias ?   o.ID as ORD_ID well thats wrong you cannot do that

Answer (score 1):

How about trying :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 
                    V_ORD_HISTORY
                AS 
                SELECT
                    a.ID as CUSTOMER_ID,
                    o.ID as ORD_ID,
                    o.PONO,
                    o.ORDERNO,
                    o.DATE_TAKEN,
                    o.ARCUSTO_ID,
                    d.ORDERS_ID,
                    d.ID as DETAIL_ID,
                    d.TOTAL_QTY_ORD,
                    d.CUMM_SHIPPED,
                    d.DISCOUNT,
                    d.UNIT_PRICE
                FROM
                    ARCUSTO a,
                    ORDERS  o,
                    ORD_DETAIL d,
                    ARINVT i
                WHERE
                    a.id= o.ARCUSTO_ID
                AND
                    o.id = d.ORDERS_ID
```

Comment: This worked. However, my view has no data for some reason, though there is data in the database?

Comment: there can be 2 possible reason for this. First, may be either of the tables you are joining is empty or second the tables data is not matching on the filter criteria. Check again your data

Comment: I suggest to remove the table `arinvt` because its not being used

Comment: Nevermind, had some conditions in there that didn't exist in the data. This has been accepted as the correct answer. Thanks XING!